# Calculate total from array

Tags: java

Two questions:
1. How do I create a method called getTotal() that traverses through the array and counts the total of the votes for all Candidates?
2. Where and how to create the method printResults() , that should transverse through the array and creates a table with columns for Candidate name, followed by votes received, and then percentage of total votes

**Candidate**

```
  public class Candidate
 {
  // instance variables 
    private int numVotes;
    private String name;

 /**
 * Constructor for objects of class InventoryItem
 */
  public Candidate(String n, int v)
  {
   // initialise instance variables
    name = n;
    numVotes = v;
   }
    public int votes() 
   {
    return numVotes;
   }
   public void setVotes(int num)
   {
     numVotes = num;
   }
   public String getName()
   {
     return name;
   }
   public void setName(String n)
   {
    name = n;
   }    
   public String toString()
   {
     return name + " received " + numVotes + " votes.";
   }
   public int getTotal(Candidate[] election)
   {

   }
```

}

**TestCandidate**

```
 public class TestCandidate
 {
   public static void printVotes(Candidate[] election) 
   {
    for(int i = 0; i < election.length; i++)
       System.out.println(election[i]);
   }

   public int getTotal(Candidate[] election)
{
  int total = 0;
  for(Candidate candidate : election )
  {
    total += candidate.numVotes;
  }
   return total;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Candidate[] election = new Candidate[5];

    // create election
    election[0] = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);
    election[1] = new Candidate("Mary Miller", 4000);        
    election[2] = new Candidate("Michael Duffy", 6000);
    election[3] = new Candidate("Tim Robinson", 2500);
    election[4] = new Candidate("Joe Ashtony", 1800);    

    System.out.println("     Results per candidate        ");
    System.out.println("______________________________");
    System.out.println();
    printVotes(election);

    System.out.println("The total of votes in election: " + getTotal() );
}
```

}

Comment: i dont think getTotal should be in Candidate class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int getTotal(Candidate[] election)
{
    int total = 0;
    for( Candidate candidate : election ) {
        total += candidate.votes();
    }
    return total;
}
```

This method and `printResults()` method in my opinion should go to some wrapper class that gathers all Candidates. For example like this:

```
class CandidatesList { 
    private Candidate[] candidates;

    public CandidatesList(Candidate[] candidates) {
        this.candidates = candidates;
    }

    public int getTotal()
    {
        int total = 0;
        for( Candidate candidate : candidates) {
            total += candidate.votes();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        int total = getTotal();
        for( Candidate candidate : candidates) {
            builder.append( String.format( "%20s | %5d | %.2f %%\n", 
                candidate.getName(), candidate.votes(), candidate.votes() / total );
        }
        return builder.toString();
    } 
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
CandidatesList list = new CandidatesList(election);
System.out.print(list);
System.out.format("Total votes: %d\n", list.getTotal());
```

Comment: Great thank you. How can I print only the total votes? System.out.println("The total number of votes is " + getTotal(Candidate[] election) );

Comment: It should work except for method names that may differ. To print total votes you need to do
    System.out.println(list.getTotal());

Comment: Before adding your code, with the code I have no, System.out.println(election.getTotal()); does not work

Comment: If you want to put getTotal method inside Candidate class that represents single person you need to pass it an array of Candidates (code for the method is in the beginning of my comment). However, this logic should not be part of single Candidate. Instead I suggest using separate CandidateList class that takes care of this. You simply need to prepare array of Candidate objects and pass it to the constructor. Then you invoke methods with no parameters since all data are insinde CandidateList.

Comment: I have it in the testCandidate class

Comment: In this case you need to declare `getTotal` method static, because you access it from a static context (main method). Reading and interpreting compiler errors is a good practice :) No, wait... It's a duty!

Comment: Can getTotal be getTotal(Candidate[] election) ? Or I dont need to pass any parameters?